# Capillary rise and excess pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

In a capillary rise energy must be provided to lift a column of liquid in a capillary above the original surface. Can you explain briefly and in molecular terms where this energy comes from?

Answer (score 0):

the work is performed by the force of attraction between the molecules of water making up the surface of the meniscus and the glass surface of the capillary tube. If that force is instead repulsive, then the meniscus surface will be depressed below the surface of the liquid when the capillary tube is inserted into it.

By spiking the water with a small amount of surfactant (like dish washing liquid), the attractive forces between adjacent water molecules at the meniscus surface are largely broken, and the meniscus will not rise as far in the capillary tube.

When properly calibrated against known standards- and knowing the diameter of the capillary bore- you can use the amount of capillary rise as a cheap, fast, and convenient way to measure the surface tension of a water sample.